# spl2cでc言語コードが生成されません

Tags: compiler

Shakespear Programming Language(spl)というプログラミング言語をやってみたいと思っているのですが、そのsplコードをc言語コードに変換するspl2cを実行しても、毎回プロンプトの下に空行ができるだけで止まってしまいます。
また、Ctrl-Dで終了させると以下のようなメッセージが表示されます。

```
Unrecognized error encountered. No code output.
```

実行環境はVirtualBoxでうごかしているChromixiumOSです。

Comment: spl って知らないので勘違いだったらすみません。 どのようにコマンドを呼び出していますか？　おそらく `spl2c splのソースファイル名 出力Cソースファイル名` のようなフォーマット（あるいは`spl2c < splのソースファイル名 > 出力Cソースファイル名`）で実行するのではないかと思います。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、 @sken2 さん、お二人とも、ありがとうございます。
` spl2c < splソースファイル > 出力Cソースファイル ` で無事C言語ソースファイルが作成されました。生成されたCのソースコードのほうも一筋縄ではいかないような状態ではあるのですが、一先ずはこれでいいかと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

面白そうだったので検索してみたのですがほとんど情報がなく、本家に全く同じ質問が見つかったくらいでした。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815043/how-to-run-shakespeare-spl-file-in-c

これ（の引用部分）によるとリダイレクト(<)を使って標準入力から読ませればいいみたいですが、それで動かないですか？